# Uploading source code for specific requirement in github

Tags: github

I have heard that, product based companies will look for what we have done outside of projects and also looking for the github profile.

In the meantime, I have created an automation application which addresses the specific requirement (Timesheet) in our organization. So, I thought of uploading this one too.

I have also done the screen cast and uploaded it to YouTube for adding in the profile (Resume).

This exact tool is not useful for all the people , but useful for the people in our organization, in which they can edit/contribute more.

Now I am having the question like, can I upload this kind of the code to GitHub?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Code on GitHub does not have to be useful to other people. You can push code there even if it is only useful to you or people in your organization.

You could also use a private repository if you do not want other people to see the code.

See: https://github.com/pricing